# how to submit jquery page on local machine

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var data = [
           { name: "Astor", product: "astor", stocklevel: "10", price: "2.99"},
           { name: "Daffodil", product: "daffodil", stocklevel: "12", price: "1.99"},
           { name: "Rose", product: "rose", stocklevel: "2", price: "4.99"},
           { name: "Peony", product: "peony", stocklevel: "0", price: "1.50"},
           { name: "Primula", product: "primula", stocklevel: "1", price: "3.12"},
           { name: "Snowdrop", product: "snowdrop", stocklevel: "15", price: "0.99"},
        ];

        var templResult = $('#flowerTmpl').tmpl(data);
        templResult.slice(0, 3).appendTo('#row1');
        templResult.slice(3).appendTo("#row2");

        $('input').focus(handleFormFocus).blur(handleFormFocus);

        function handleFormFocus(e) {
            var borderVal = e.type == "focus" ? "medium solid green" : "";
            $(this).css("border", borderVal);
        }     

    });
    </script>
    <script id="flowerTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <div class="dcell">    
            <img src="${product}.png"/>
            <label for="${product}">${name}: </label>
            <input name="${product}" value="0" required />
        </div>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Jacqui's Flower Shop</h1>
    <form method="post" action="http://node.jacquisflowershop.com/order">
        <div id="oblock">        
            <div class="dtable">
                <div id="row1" class="drow">
                </div>
                <div id="row2"class="drow">
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="buttonDiv"><button type="submit">Place Order</button></div>                    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi,

I am learning JQuery but I want to know the output from a form submission.  how can I submit a form on a local machine.  It's not like .NET and using localhost.

What do i do to get JQuery sumbitting forms on my local machine - just plain text in the browser

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. jQuery certainly also can be used locally, but you need a form of communication, typically http. For that you do need an http server, which may well work locally. That should not be an issue. Question is: if you do _not_ what to use a local http server (whyever), then what is jQuery going to communicate with? There are alternatives, but this is why your question is unclear. So what is it you want to do? What do you mean by "I want to know the output from a form submission"?

Comment: hi, i just wanted to test the page out locally.  Maybe I am missing some things.  I would use anything to try it locally but I don't know what.  Maybe I don't have anything in the above page that would enable a form submission and display of second page.  Currently page just posts to http://node.jacquisflowershop.com/order but i thought i could try local host.  maybe its a bit simplistic

Comment: Sorry, still unclear. You certainly can change the form target to any url you like, also a local one, whatever local here means for you. Alternatively do not send it at all, but visualize it instead for debugging purposes? You can simply make a popup using jQuery or log to console which is the typical things to test and debug stuff.

Comment: Debug sounds like what I want.  I just want to see what is passed over to the next page.  Instead of submit to a new page - use the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, when considering the comments to the question this might get you started:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').attr('action', '');
  $('form button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submit button clicked, here is the form to be posted: ');
    console.log($('form').serialize());
  });
});
```

This prevents the submission of the form and reacts on the click event on the submit button. You can output whatever you like. Removing the content of the forms action attribute is not really required, it is just a safety measurement...

here is a jsfiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/eghp78f2/